# How to pass data From one Scene to another in ReactNaive

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

My Question i have two Scene `OnceScene` and `TwoScene` I want to Navigate from `OnceScene` to `TwoScene` and at the same time i want to pass some array from 1st the 2nd so for that i have written the below code

```
 this.props.navigator.push({
     id: "productdetails",
```

> passProps: {arr: arr[rowID]}

```
   });
```

you can see i am passing the array in `passProps` but how can i acess that array in `TwoScene` Its seems simple but since i am new i dont have much idea.

Comment: Why don't you use redux? You can study [this](https://github.com/start-react/native-starter-kit) starter project for how to do it.

Comment: already solved that please check my answer..

Comment: Great! At some point you will need to add redux to your project and you will see that these kind of actions will be much easier. So sooner you add redux better for you, unless you have a specific reason for not using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what i was missing ,forgot to declare

```
  return (<ProductDetails title="ProductDetails"
```

navigator={navigator}

> {...route.passProps}  route={route}

/>)

on my return component. This is the reason i was getting `undefined` value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using react-native router?

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

Also answering to your question it seems like you are passing the data through props. So on the next screen you can access these props like: this.props.foo (of course you need to declare it on the second screen somehow to access it.)