# Pass data From one Scene to another in ReactNaive

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm new in react native, i have two Scene OnceScene and TwoScene I want to Navigate from OnceScene to TwoScene and at the same time i want to pass some string or array from 1st the 2nd so for that i have written the below code

```
 let nextRoute = {
      component: TwoScene,
      title: 'TwoScene',
      passProps: { myProp: 'bar', searchText: 'pass data', }
    };
                this.props.navigator.push(nextRoute);
```

you can see i am passing the string in passProps but how can i acess that string in TwoScene Its seems simple but since i am new i dont have much idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data From one Scene to another in ReactNaive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42621845/how-to-pass-data-from-one-scene-to-another-in-reactnaive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `myProp` and `searchText` *should* be accessible as `this.props.myProp` and `this.props.searchText` in TwoScene

Answer (score 1):

You can write this to TwoScene:

```
const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
```

In params, you get pass data :

```
params.passProps.myProp
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44298025/react-native-0-44-stack-navigator-example/44299087?noredirect=1#comment75610297_44299087  can fix this issue ?