# React Native 0.44 -- Stack Navigator example

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to create an Android version of my React Native app but I'm having problems getting my head around the Android navigator.

[download sample code](https://ufile.io/lr8x5)

Comment: duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297787/pass-data-from-one-scene-to-another-in-reactnaive

Comment: Which code write? give code than solve problem

Comment: @NidhiPatel updated sample code Pls solve the problem

Comment: @Ravindhiran i have answered your question check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AppNav file you have written wrong code for import, do as below AppNav.js

**AppNav.js**

```
import Splash from './Splash';
import Home from './Home';
import Login from './Login';
import Register from './Register';
```

Second problem is you haven't export your files.
Add last line in All files

**Home.js**

```
export default Home;
```

**Splash.js**

```
export default Splash;
```

**Login.js**

```
export default Login;
```

**Register.js**

```
export default Home;
```

I have done this changes in your code and its works.

Comment: how to implement a  custom back button action?

Comment: write this code to back action method `this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.back());`

Comment: i want to integrate tabbar with stack navigator how can i do this?

Comment: can you answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44719103/singleton-object-in-react-native

Answer (score 3):

First create a file like **appNav.js**

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import Splash from './splash.js';
import Home from './home.js';
import Login from './login.js';
import Register from './register.js';
export const AppNav = StackNavigator({
    Splash: { screen: Splash },
    Home: { screen: Home },
    Login: { screen: Login },
    Register: { screen: Register }
});

export default AppNav;
```

then in **index.android.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import AppNav from './components/appnav.js'
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeApp', () => AppNav);
```

use it like this, in **splash.js**

in render() function add this to use navigation

```
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
```

now you can use it under any button like

```
<Button
          onPress={() => navigate('Home')}
          title="Go Home"
        />
```

this should look like...

```
    class Splash extends Component {
      static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Splash', //header:null <= if you want to hide the header
      };
      render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>Hello, This is splash</Text>
            <Button
              onPress={() => navigate('Home')}
              title="Go Home"
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

you can dig up more [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/)

and its that simple. 
cheers

Comment: can you share me which you tested sample app ?

Comment: @Ravindhiran :- this is pretty straightforward and working properly with my app.just create a demo project with two or more screens and you will be able to navigate using StackNavigator.

But if I get time I shall make a demo and github that.

Comment: pls refer this url : https://ufile.io/6c4yz    but always getting error i dont know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: I checked the zip
you need to put the path properly in appNav.js

if your home.js is not in same folder then you need to put the proper path that refers to home.js

Please check all the paths in all of your files

Comment: how to implement a custom back button action? this.props.navigation.pop(); not working

Comment: use this.props.navigation.goBack(); instead of  this.props.navigation.pop();

Comment: i want to add Tabbar with stack navigator how can i do this?