# react native navigator:Undefined is not an object(evaluating this.props.navigation.navigate)

Tags: navigation, react-native

I'm not able to understand how to implement navigation in react-native.
as per the [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html) i have installed the plugin and integrated the code but it keeps giving the error

**Undefined is not an object(evaluating this.props.navigation.navigate)**

Below is the index.android.js

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import Login from './src/pages/Login';
import Home from './src/pages/Home';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

export default class ECart extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <App />
    );
  }
}

const App = StackNavigator({
Login:{screen:Login},
Home: {screen: Home}
});



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ECart', () => ECart);
```

The Login page

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  Alert,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import Home from './Home';


export default class Login extends Component {



    constructor(props) {
         super(props);
        this.state = {};
        this.onButtonPress=this.onButtonPress.bind(this);

    }


    onButtonPress= () => {
       alert("ok");
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        navigate(Home);
        };

    render() {

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

                <View style={{justifyContent: 'center',alignItems: 'center',height:250}}>
                    <Image style={{}} source={require('../img/ic_launcher.png')} />
                </View>
              <View style={styles.wrapper}>

                    <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
                        <View style={styles.iconWrap}>
                        <Image style={styles.icon} source={require('../img/icon/ic_email.png')}/>
                        </View>

                        <TextInput
                          style={styles.input}
                          placeholder="Username"
                          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                          placeholderTextColor="#939598"
                        />

                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.inputWrap}>

                        <View style={styles.iconWrap}>
                          <Image style={styles.icon} source={require('../img/icon/ic_lock.png')}/>
                        </View>
                        <TextInput
                          style={styles.input}
                          placeholder="Password"
                          secureTextEntry
                          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                          placeholderTextColor="#939598"
                        />

                    </View>

                    <TouchableOpacity
                      activeOpacity={0.5}
                      onPress={this.onButtonPress}>
                      <View style={styles.button}>
                          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
                      </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5}>
                      <View style={styles.textWrap}>
                          <Text>Forgot Password.</Text><Text>Reset here</Text>
                      </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

              </View>

                <View style={styles.bottomTextWrap}>
                    <Text style={{}}> By clicking Sign In, you agree to our Terms and that you have read our Data Policy, including our Cookie Use.
                    </Text>
                </View>

              <View style={styles.bottomTextWrap}>
               <Text> Copyright  2017 Suyati Technologies
               </Text>
             </View>

        </View>



    );
  }

}

const styles= StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
  },

  inputWrap:{
    flexDirection:"row",
    marginVertical:10,
    height:50,
    borderWidth:1,
    borderColor:'#939598',
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
  },
  textWrap:{
    flexDirection:"row",
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    marginVertical:10,
    paddingHorizontal:20
  },
  bottomTextWrap:{
    flex:1,
    flexDirection:"row",
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems:'flex-end',
    marginVertical:10
  },
  text:{
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center'
  },

  input:{
    flex:1,
    paddingHorizontal:10,
    backgroundColor:"transparent",
    color:'#939598'
  },
  wrapper:{
    paddingHorizontal:30
  },
  iconWrap  :{
    paddingHorizontal:7,
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    borderColor:'#939598'
  },
  icon:{
    width:20,
    height:20
  },
  button:{
    backgroundColor:'#13AFBC',
    paddingVertical:10,
    marginVertical:10,
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center'
  },
  buttonText:{
    color:'#FFFFFF',
    fontSize:18
  }
})
```

I'm trying to navigate to the home screen.
I'm finding react-native a bit difficult.
If anyone could guide me in the right direction it will be very helpful as i'm stuck at it and need a new approach.

EDIT-I changed the code but still it wont navigate.I get the alert but it stays on the loginpage

Thanks!

Comment: this answer can help you [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44298025/react-native-0-44-stack-navigator-example/44299087#44299087)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you have copy-pasted code from different sources(maybe tutorials) and hope it will work, but usually it doesn't. In your code you have several mistakes.

First of all, in `index.android.js` file you have `ECart` component, which is passed to `AppRegistry.registerComponent()` function. So, this component is a starting point for you application. You also have `App` variable, which is actually also a component, but you never use it. So now, your app doesn't use react-navigation, as it is not included anyhow. In order to use navigation library, you have to pass it to the app registry on some level. For example like this

```
const App = StackNavigator({
   Login: {screen: Login},
   Home: {screen: Home},
});

export default class ECart extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <App />
    );
  }
}
```

This way, `Ecart` is passed to AppRegistry, and it has `App` (navigation component), which will handle navigations. Because `App` is responsible for navigation, you should declare your 'routes' and corresponding components that navigation component, like i included `Login Screen` above. Because `Login` is first in your `StackNavigator` declaration, it will be first screen when app is loaded.

Now, every compononent that you passed through `StackNavigator` will have `navigation` prop, passed by react-navigation. With that prop, you can navigate to other screens in your app. So, because you in your code `Login` component is not passed to `StackNavigator`, `this.props.navigation` will be `undefined`. And when you try to access `this.props.navigation.navigate`, it will throw an error, where it says, that undefined is not an object.This explains your main error, but it is not only error in the code you paste here.

In your `Login` component, you have

```
onButtonPress= () => {
    navigate(Home, { name: 'Jane' });
};
```

which calls `navigate` function, but it is not declared anyware. So, when  you will resolve first error, you will see another error when you press your button, `Undefined is not a function`. So, to solve this you have to do two things. First, declare navigate function, second bind onButtonPress method.

```
onButtonPress() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation; 
    navigate('Home', { name: 'Jane' });
};
```

and bind this method like

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};

    this.onButtonPress=this.onButtonPress.bind(this);
}
```

If you are thinking, what the hell is binding, take a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhbhD1HR5vk)

Comment: ok saw the video and changed the code but it still wont navigate to home screen.editing the question with the updated code

Comment: ok its working now.The mistake was in the navigate call.Home should be a string. navigate('Home'); Works now.Thanks